# Is it possible to load Highcharts options from a file?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

In a project, I want to work with Highcharts, but instead of putting the options code directly on to the website I rather would like to see it in an extra file, e.g. charts.js. Is it possible?
What I have done so far:
I created the general chart and it works. I tried to put the options code as shown on Highcharts in a file called charts.js and include it into the header. But it doesn't work, shows an error #13.

The code I used was

```
function getPointCategoryName(point, dimension) {
    var series = point.series,
        isY = dimension === 'y',
        axis = series[isY ? 'yAxis' : 'xAxis'];
    return axis.categories[point[isY ? 'y' : 'x']];
}

Highcharts.chart('container', {

    chart: {
        type: 'heatmap',
        marginTop: 40,
        marginBottom: 80,
        plotBorderWidth: 1
    },


    title: {
        text: 'Sales per employee per weekday'
    },

    xAxis: {
        categories: ['Alexander', 'Marie', 'Maximilian', 'Sophia', 'Lukas', 'Maria', 'Leon', 'Anna', 'Tim', 'Laura']
    },

    yAxis: {
        categories: ['Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday'],
        title: null,
        reversed: true
    },

    accessibility: {
        point: {
            descriptionFormatter: function (point) {
                var ix = point.index + 1,
                    xName = getPointCategoryName(point, 'x'),
                    yName = getPointCategoryName(point, 'y'),
                    val = point.value;
                return ix + '. ' + xName + ' sales ' + yName + ', ' + val + '.';
            }
        }
    },

    colorAxis: {
        min: 0,
        minColor: '#FFFFFF',
        maxColor: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0]
    },

    legend: {
        align: 'right',
        layout: 'vertical',
        margin: 0,
        verticalAlign: 'top',
        y: 25,
        symbolHeight: 280
    },

    tooltip: {
        formatter: function () {
            return '<b>' + getPointCategoryName(this.point, 'x') + '</b> sold <br><b>' +
                this.point.value + '</b> items on <br><b>' + getPointCategoryName(this.point, 'y') + '</b>';
        }
    },

    series: [{
        name: 'Sales per employee',
        borderWidth: 1,
        data: [[0, 0, 10], [0, 1, 19], [0, 2, 8], [0, 3, 24], [0, 4, 67], [1, 0, 92], [1, 1, 58], [1, 2, 78], [1, 3, 117], [1, 4, 48], [2, 0, 35], [2, 1, 15], [2, 2, 123], [2, 3, 64], [2, 4, 52], [3, 0, 72], [3, 1, 132], [3, 2, 114], [3, 3, 19], [3, 4, 16], [4, 0, 38], [4, 1, 5], [4, 2, 8], [4, 3, 117], [4, 4, 115], [5, 0, 88], [5, 1, 32], [5, 2, 12], [5, 3, 6], [5, 4, 120], [6, 0, 13], [6, 1, 44], [6, 2, 88], [6, 3, 98], [6, 4, 96], [7, 0, 31], [7, 1, 1], [7, 2, 82], [7, 3, 32], [7, 4, 30], [8, 0, 85], [8, 1, 97], [8, 2, 123], [8, 3, 64], [8, 4, 84], [9, 0, 47], [9, 1, 114], [9, 2, 31], [9, 3, 48], [9, 4, 91]],
        dataLabels: {
            enabled: true,
            color: '#000000'
        }
    }],

    responsive: {
        rules: [{
            condition: {
                maxWidth: 500
            },
            chartOptions: {
                yAxis: {
                    labels: {
                        formatter: function () {
                            return this.value.charAt(0);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }]
    }

});
```

Is there a way to put the code into a fail and let it work as it would if code, CDN and Co. are on one page? Or is there anything I do wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Highcharts error #13 means that Highcharts is unable to find the HTML element to render the chart in. From your description it looks like your script is fired before DOM is fully loaded. As a solution put all your code from `chart.js` file into `DOMContentLoaded` event callback function:

```
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', (event) => {
    // chart.js
});
```

Or just put your script before the closing `</body>`:

```
<html>
  ....
  <body>
     ....
     <script type="text/javascript" src="chart.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```